# Is there a more efficient caching method than this for storing shortest path in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, caching, optimization, hashmap

I am using A* algorithm to return a List of the shortest path between a given start and destination. My current caching system uses a hashmap containing a hash map like so:

```
    // Start -> Destination -> Next Step
Map<Node,Map<Node,Node>> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

An example would be  A->B->C->D
We could retrieve this path once its cached by doing

cache.get(A).get(D) // Returns B as its the next step.

cache.get(B).get(D) // Returns C as its the next step.

cache.get(C).get(D) // Returns D as its the next step.

I can check if the path I'm calculating is currently cached by using

```
public Boolean isInCache(Node start,Node destination){
    return cache.containsKey(start)&&cache.get(start).containsKey(destination);
}
```

I can assemble the remaining path using this method

```
    /*
Returns a path to a destination from a given point in a previously cached path.
 */
public List<Node> getCachedPath(Node start,Node destination){
    ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
    //If we don't have a path just return an empty list.
    if(!isInCache(start,destination))return path;
    //iterate our hashmaps compiling our list by adding the next step each time.
    Node next = start;
    while(next !=null){
        path.add(next);
        next = cache.getOrDefault(next,null).getOrDefault(destination,null);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Here's how I initially store a path to the cache

```
    /*
Inserts a list of calculated nodes to a destination
 */
public void insertInCache(List<Node> nodes){
    // make a reference to the last node, this is our destination.
    Node destination = nodes.get(nodes.size()-1);
    //iterate nodes in the list
    for(int i = 0; i<nodes.size(); i++){
        Node node = nodes.get(i);
        //create new map if it is absent
        cache.putIfAbsent(node,new HashMap<>());
        //if there is a "next step" in our list then lets take it and put in in the map as the value.
        if(nodes.size()>i+1)
            cache.get(node).put(destination,nodes.get(i+1));
    }
}
```

This is great for storing paths and quickly assembling previously cached paths, although it is unable to retrieve subpaths of a cached path. An example would be
Trying to get A->C when we only have A->D cached, A->D has the directions from A->C inside of it, I am trying to figure out the most optimal solution for this issue.

Comment: _I am using A* algorithm_ - no, not really. You provide no scoring or heuristic measure to determine the shortest path. Your _path_ is a linked list. The issue is that you have buried your intermediate steps inside the sub-structure of the cache's value map and the intermediate steps are not available as a "destination" as you've defined your structure. So this test `!isInCache(start,destination)` can't find the intermediate node.

Comment: These are the methods I use to cache after the path has been calculated using A* (Returns a List<Node>), I did not post that portion of code. I use scoring based on the distance squared between each node. I have access to the intermediate steps when I cache it the first time, maybe I can do something there to allow subpath navigation. Maybe there is a data-structure that might be more efficient here.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I think it may be a simple matter of adjusting your `isInCache()` method to also look into the the inner Map's values for the destination.